# Библиотеки для работы с графикой

Tags: python, 3d

Какая библиотека больше подходит для создания простой игры аля тетрис или doodle jump.
При этом желательно , чтобы эта библиотека имела русскую документацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pygame, можно прикупить еще книгу Майкла Доусона для старта.

Answer (score 0):

PyGame и Blender3D

Comment: blender для тетриса? Однако. vpython (пакет python-visual)